# jquery validator HTML form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

i am trying to validate a form  text box using jquery validator, it works fine with the zend-framwork forms but it does not work at with any HTML form and here is the code :
1)this is the script in the html page :

```
<script>
    $("#newsletter").validate({
        rules: {
            newsletter_input:{
                email: true
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

2) this is the form:

```
  <form id="newsletter">
  <input type="text" name="newsletter-input" id="newsletter_input" class="clickable_search email " title="enter your e-mail" value="enter your email" />
  <input type="submit" value="" id="newsletter-submit" />
   </form>
```

what am i missing here ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <form id ="myform">
 <input type="text" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" class="clickable_search required email " title="أدخل البريد الإلكتروني" value="أدخل البريد الإلكتروني" />
 <input type="submit" value="" id="newsletter-submit" />
 </form>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
  field: {
  required: true,
  email: true
     }
    }
   });
  });
  </script>
```

this is the only way that worked with me to put an id on the form

Answer (score 1):

You're including the jQuery script on the page?

Try simply:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#newsletter").validate();
});
</script>
```

And add `required` as a class to the newsletter email input.

```
<form id="newsletter">
<input type="text" name="newsletter-input" id="newsletter_input" class="clickable_search email required" title="enter your e-mail" value="enter your email" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="newsletter-submit" />
</form>
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$("#newsletter-submit").click(function() {
    $("#newsletter").validate({
        ..
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules property of the validate object works on the name property of the element, not the id, therefore your script code should be:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#newsletter").validate({
            rules: {
                "newsletter-input":{
                    email: true
                }
            }
       });
    });
</script>
```

Note the - not _.

Also worth noting that due to the dash in the field name, which isn't a legal javascript identifier, you'll need to quote the field name for the rule to work.

Personally, I would avoid using dashes in the name and id properties and use Camel case instead

Comment: i have changed the name and avoid all dashes and still same problem not validating

Comment: Just noticed you were also missing the document ready event hook.